# What diagram would be the best to describe the situation

Tags: uml, engineering, diagrams

I am working on a software integrated with the hardware component. I need to create a simple diagram to express that:

1. Certain activity runs in a cycle (the device continously monitor a temperature)
2. When the temperature deviates from the baseline and remains so for 10 seconds, a function is called

I am writing a high level document and I am not sure how to capture this - UML diagrams do not seem to be suitable..but maybe an activity diagram?

Comment: A flowchart could probably capture this idea nicely.

Comment: Thanks. If I understand it correctly, flowchart is basically the UML activity diagram, just not "formalized".

Comment: Actually, the UML activity diagram is a flowchart with funny-shaped boxes.

Comment: Well, a flowchart is just an activity diagram with normal-shaped boxes. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either activity diagram or sequence diagram (they are pretty much two views of the same thing).

(EDIT: whoops in earlier text I was confusing correlation diagram with activity diagram; they are really similar. Either it's been too long, or else there are just too many damn diagrams available. ;) )

Sequence diagrams have notation for looping; the message that follows the deviation would just come right after the loop.

...

The boxes around an activity diagrams just become the boxes at the top of the sequence diagram. I used to really like activity diagrams, but came to find sequence diagrams easier to manage -- personal preference. BTW there's a good online tool for playing with sequence diagrams:
http://websequencediagrams.com

...

Also, you're describing a state machine, so a state diagram might also work well. The states are

- initial
- normal -- no deviation
- alert -- deviation detected, but less than 10 seconds
- trigger -- deviation detected for 10 seconds

...and then back to normal.

In any case, there are a few good choices. It's a small enough problem that you could do it each way and see what looks best.

Comment: Thank you. In the sequence diagram, I would not be sure about the objects. But isnt there the loop ntoation also for the activity diagram?

Comment: Edited answer with comment :)

Comment: Thank you. One more thing - as the deviation has to be occuring for at least 10 seconds, I assume the message cannot just follow the loop. I am not too familial with the sequence diagram..

Comment: I'm just displaying my preference; activity diagram may be best. A thought just occured to me ... this is kind of a state machine, so a state diagram would also work. I'll add that above.